# What is postgresql_psycopg2?

Tags: database, postgresql

What is postgresql_psycopg2 ? Difference from postgresql ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is (one of) the Python bindings to the PostgreSQL client library. It has nothing to do with PostgreSQL itself other than it allows Python programs to access a PostgreSQL server.

Comment: Or more specifically - the Django's database [configuration parameter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#get-your-database-running) which instructs it to use the psycopg2 driver (instead 'postgresql' for psycopg1).

Comment: what is the best for django ? postgresql or postgresql_psycopg2 ?

Answer (score 4):

When you connect to your PostgreSQL database, you most likely will use Psycopg (imported into python, allows you to write SQL code and submit it to the database). 
postgresql_psycopg2 belongs to Psycopg2 (second version of Psycopg), while postgresql belongs to Psycopg (the first version).

As intgr mentioned, if using with Django, Psycopg2 is recommended (Psycopg isn't supported anymore)